# Find first photo in each album inside an array of photos with AlbumIds

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I need to find the first photo of each album. The photo's are listed in an array that includes an albumId on each photo like this:

[
 {
   id: 1,
   albumId: 1,
 }, 
 {
   id: 2,
   albumId: 1,
 }, 
 {
   id: 3,
   albumId: 2,
 }, 
 {
   id: 4,
   albumId: 2,
 }
]

So each object is a photo, that's connected in an album. What I'd like to do is iterate over this array and create a new array that just includes the first photo in each album assuming that the original array is in order (so the first time a new albumId appears, you can assume that's the first photo in the album).

Currently this is the code I have:

```
let lastAlbumId = null;
const newAlbumArray = [];

albums.forEach(photo => {
  if (lastAlbumId === null) {
    lastAlbumId = photo.albumId;
    newAlbumArray.push(photo);
  } else if (lastAlbumId !== photo.albumId) {
    lastAlbumId = photo.albumId;
    newAlbumArray.push(photo);
  }
});

return newAlbumArray;
```

this code works, but I feel like there must be a cleaner way to do this with something like filter() or find(), any suggestions?

Comment: If your objective isn't to rewrite the function from scratch, I'd suggest to use one of the many `uniq` implementations available, such as the one from `lodash`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to track the albums that were already added:

```js
const photos = [{ id: 1, albumId: 1, }, { id: 2, albumId: 1, }, { id: 3, albumId: 2, }, { id: 4, albumId: 2, } ]

const albums = new Set();
const result = photos.filter(o => !albums.has(o.albumId) && albums.add(o.albumId))

console.log(result)
```

Another option is to [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the array to a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), using the `albumId` as the key. The photo can be added to the Map, only if the album's id doesn't already exists. When done, we convert the Map to an array by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the Map's [values iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values):

```js
const photos = [{ id: 1, albumId: 1, }, { id: 2, albumId: 1, }, { id: 3, albumId: 2, }, { id: 4, albumId: 2, } ]

const result = [...photos.reduce((m, o) => m.has(o.albumId) ? m :  m.set(o.albumId, o), new Map).values()]

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `reduce`.

```js
const albums = [ { id: 1, albumId: 1, }, { id: 2, albumId: 1, }, { id: 3, albumId: 2, }, { id: 4, albumId: 2, } ];

const output = Object.values(albums.reduce((accu, {id, albumId}) => {
    if(!accu[albumId]) accu[albumId] = {id, albumId};
    return accu;
}, {}));

console.log(output);
```